# Java error when restarting server STANDARD_IMPORTS RequestURI=/

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty

I'm using Hudson and often when I've done a build, the server doesn't appear to have started properly with this error:

Does anyone know what it relates to?

```
HTTP ERROR: 500

Unable to load class for JSP
RequestURI=/

Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:598)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:147)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:315)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
```

This alternates between

```
HTTP ERROR: 500

STANDARD_IMPORTS
RequestURI=/

Caused by:

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: STANDARD_IMPORTS
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.PageInfo.(PageInfo.java:100)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:107)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:276)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:264)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:563)
```

And in the server logs

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:137)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at launcher.JettyLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```